# Auto set null in entity properties after pushing context

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

Is there any option in hibernate where entity properties with fetch mode is lazy be null?

I have an entity and I want to choose which properties should be loaded. I do this with the help of "EntityGraphsProfile", but this method doesn’t suit me, because the properties that I didn’t define there have the meaning not nul but  HibernateProxy.

```
@NamedEntityGraphs(
        @NamedEntityGraph(
                name = DepartmentEntity.EntityGraph.DEFAULT,
                attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode(DepartmentEntity.Skeleton.TITLE),
                        @NamedAttributeNode(DepartmentEntity.Skeleton.SUB_DEPARTMENTS),
                        @NamedAttributeNode(DepartmentEntity.Skeleton.USERS)
                }
        )
)
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class DepartmentEntity
        extends Entity
        implements TreeNodeEntity<DepartmentEntity>,
        CollectorEntity<UserEntity>,
        Department {

    @NotNull
    String title;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    DepartmentEntity parent;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = Skeleton.PARENT, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    Set<DepartmentEntity> subDepartments;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = UserEntity.Skeleton.DEPARTMENT, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    Set<UserEntity> users;

    @Override
    public Collection<DepartmentEntity> getChildes() {
        return subDepartments;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<UserEntity> getCollection() {
        return users;
    }

    public interface Skeleton {
        String TITLE = "title";
        String PARENT = "parent";
        String SUB_DEPARTMENTS = "subDepartments";
        String USERS = "users";
    }

    public interface EntityGraph {
        String DEFAULT = "default";
    }
}
```

How to make the attribute "parent" which is not included in my graph after extraction was not hiberanteproxy but null

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more (with example)?

Comment: Sure. 
I want to select the attributes to extract, 
for this I use EntityGraphs, 
but I don’t like that attributes that I did not specify in EntityGraph are retrieved as HibernateProxy and not null